# Can't use BootstrapSwitch() into my main project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using requirejs to load my javascript files into the project.

As normal, I'm loading bootstrap_switch considering all it's known dependencies and the javascript is being loaded without problem.

For example, given the following element, to style it i would just need to do $('#my_el').bootstrapSwitch()

```
<input id="my_el" type="checkbox" data-size="small">
```

And that's all fine since the element is created.
The problem occurs when the plugin tries to add the css classes to the element.

All the code that should be executed is returned as a string as you can see below:

```
<div class="function () {
              var classes;
              classes = [&quot;&quot; + _this.name];
              classes.push(_this.options.state ? &quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-on&quot; : &quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-off&quot;);
              if (_this.options.size != null) {
                classes.push(&quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-&quot; + _this.options.size);
              }
              if (_this.options.animate) {
                classes.push(&quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-animate&quot;);
              }
              if (_this.options.disabled) {
                classes.push(&quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-disabled&quot;);
              }
              if (_this.options.readonly) {
                classes.push(&quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-readonly&quot;);
              }
              if (_this.$element.attr(&quot;id&quot;)) {
                classes.push(&quot;&quot; + _this.name + &quot;-id-&quot; + (_this.$element.attr(&quot;id&quot;)));
              }
              return classes.join(&quot; &quot;);
            }"><div><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary">ON</span><label for="passage_valide">&nbsp;</label><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default">OFF</span><input id="passage_valide" type="checkbox" data-size="small"></div></div>
```

But, I tried to create a raw jsfiddle with the same Javascript file that i'm using inside the project and it works. 
http://goo.gl/Mco5rR

**EDIT**

Problem seems to be other after changing from BootstrapSwitch.js to a minified version of the code.

```
<div class="has-switch switch-animate switch-off" tabindex="0"><div><span class="switch-left">ON</span><label for="passage_valide">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">OFF</span><div class="has-switch switch-animate switch-off" tabindex="0"><div><span class="switch-left">ON</span><label for="passage_valide">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">OFF</span><input id="passage_valide" type="checkbox" data-size="small"></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I solved  temporarily  erasing line 75 and 95 at bootstrap-switch.js

```
    -75  return function() {
var classes;
              classes = ["" + _this.name];
              classes.push(_this.options.state ? "" + _this.name + "-on" : "" + _this.name + "-off");
              if (_this.options.size != null) {
                classes.push("" + _this.name + "-" + _this.options.size);
              }
              if (_this.options.animate) {
                classes.push("" + _this.name + "-animate");
              }
              if (_this.options.disabled) {
                classes.push("" + _this.name + "-disabled");
              }
              if (_this.options.readonly) {
                classes.push("" + _this.name + "-readonly");
              }
              if (_this.$element.attr("id")) {
                classes.push("" + _this.name + "-id-" + (_this.$element.attr("id")));
              }
              return classes.join(" ");
    -95 };
```